# How to generate a pdf report with math/calculus results

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying for the first time generate a pdf report with math results, and I'm asking for help here because I allready searched online and didn´t found anything relatable.
I tried adpating a code that I found and I added the variable that I want to export to the pdf, in this case "C", however didn´t work out. Any idea?

Code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
pdf = FPDF() 

a = 1
b = 1
C = a+b
   
pdf.add_page() 
  
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 25) 
  
# create a cell 
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "a+b =", C, 
        ln = 1, align = 'C') 
  
  
pdf.output("a.pdf")
```

Comment: Should it not be `txt = "a+b ="+C, `  ?  --

Comment: I tried but appeared this: "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: Sorry -- `txt = "a+b ="+str(C),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not concatenating correctly .. Python uses `+` and you need to convert your integer to a string with `str()`

```
txt = "a+b ="+str(C),
```